# Change data field type using access query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to change a single field data type from Long Integer type to Decimal, this is easily done by just using properties or design view.

However I want to know if this is possible using a query or perhaps a short VBA script? I can't add a new field, it has to be the existing one. We aso have to do this back and forth, depending on which program is reading the database.

The issue is we are in a transistion period between two programs. We have Microstation V8i with an add-on that reads data from the .mdb (32bit connection) database where the fields and tables are predefined and this specific field is a Long Integer. The other program is Microstation ConnectEdition which uses an updated version of the add-on which has a connection to an almost similar database (64 bit), however the developer of the update to the add-on has changed this field to a Decimal (among a few other things).

Since we currently use both programs and need to able to use both databases interchangeably, I'm working on a creating a combined Macro/Query that changes the necessary parts. This data type change is the last thing I need to do in order for this to be more automatic.

Edit-Added VBA:

```
Public Function changeDataType1()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim table As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
strSql = "ALTER TABLE feature ALTER COLUMN mslink DECIMAL(18,0);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
strSQL1 = "ALTER TABLE ugfeature ALTER COLUMN feature DECIMAL(18,0);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL1

Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Use views(queries), which convert data type, esp if you only need reading (at least from one application). Well, it is hard to imagine, why both programs cannot read from integer or decimal anyway - formatting issues?

Comment: Can you explain what issues you are running into that you feel the need to do it this way?  I agree with Arvo that using a view would be the best option or provide us some more information so we may help you find a better solution.

Comment: @Arvo Thanks for replying, I've tried added more information. The data type change is a necessary according to the developers of the add-on.

Comment: Does Microstation older add-on give an error, when you use Decimal instead of Long Integer? Technically such data should be readable and writable without problems; of course it is possible that add-on checks field type and errors out. If this is so and you need to write data in both add-ons, then views may not be a solution, at least not in MS Access.

Comment: Ah, I forgot - if you really need to change column type, then official docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Will there be simultaneous users from each program? Won't there be conflicts?

Comment: @Arvo It doesn't check for field types so this works brilliantly for new databases as all will be decimal . For existing databases that are already created it's a different story. June7, there can only be one user all together regardless of new or old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the field between those data types by executing `ALTER TABLE` statements from an ADO connection. (See Allen Browne's [note about DECIMAL support](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html#_ftn7).)

```vb
strSQL = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN switch_type LONG;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL

strSQL = "ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER COLUMN switch_type DECIMAL(18,9);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL
```

I tested those examples in the Access Immediate window, so it should be easy to incorporate them into a VBA procedure, if that's your preference.